# ocmod extension in open cart2

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, ocmod

I cannot get the ocmod extension working.... I found the only documentation file on ocmod extension [here](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/wiki/Modification-System), and I think that I followed the rules, but still i cannot reach the desired effect... the variable from the store.php file is not visible for the other tpl file (main.tpl)

So I want to add a template file to show the variable from the Store module. the template file is located at /catalog/view/theme/journal2/template/journal2/menu/main.tpl

My code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<modification>
  <name>Store Allstores Modification</name>
  <code>AC_Store_Allstores</code>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <author>AC</author>
  <link></link>
  <file path="catalog/controller/module/store.php">
    <operation>
        <search><![CDATA[
        return $this->load->view($this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/module/store.tpl', $data);
        ]]></search>
        <add position="After"><![CDATA[
        $this->load->view($this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/journal2/menu/main.tpl', $data);
        ]]></add>
    </operation>
  </file>  
</modification>
```

Could anyone point to what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You have missed `</modification>` at the end of your file, I've added it, and it worked as I excepted.

Comment: The matter of fact I have this tag in the actual file. But nevertheless it doesn't work. It doesn't break anything, but the desired variables are not availiable in the main.tpl. For more information: module Stores is enabled but not assigned to any layout. The site uses theme Journal 2. I